# ASP nested if not working

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5

The following code snippet isn't working, can someone help me identify the problem. I'm using ASP on IIS 7.0

Code:

```
<%If session("var") <> "" Then
    If( instr(strSQL("Platform"), session("osversion")) > 0  ) Then %>
        <input type="image" src="images/download2.gif" name="submit" value="submit" />
    <%Else %>
        <p style="font-weight:bold"> SOME ERROR MESSAGE</p>
    <%End If %>        
<%Else %>
    <input type="image" src="images/download2.gif" name="submit" value="submit" />
<%End If %>
```

Is the problem related to IIS 7.0 configuration for classic ASP?

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"? What happens? What are the expected results? Try outputting what session("var") is before the statements

Comment: Is there an error? Please include it in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the "`()`" in the nested `If`. Like code below:

```
<%If session("var") <> "" Then
    If instr(strSQL("Platform"), session("osversion")) > 0  Then %>
        <input type="image" src="images/download2.gif" name="submit" value="submit" />
    <%Else %>
        <p style="font-weight:bold"> SOME ERROR MESSAGE</p>
    <%End If %>        
<%Else %>
    <input type="image" src="images/download2.gif" name="submit" value="submit" />
<%End If %>
```

Now, what ever happends in the first if condition `If session("var") <> "" Then`, there should always be an output because of `<%Else %>`. The problem will be trim to the `nested if`. Check the values of `strSQL("Platform")` and `session("osversion")`. If those two are OK, check now `instr(,)`. You can even do `If instr(strSQL("Platform"), session("osversion")) > 0  Then` changed to `If true  Then` just to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to avoid the cluttering of <% and %>, it makes it unreadable.
- Second do not repeat the same strings in different places in your
  code.
- Third try to combine logic.
- Fourth pull out the strings

the code...

- Proposition A: session("var") <> ""
- Proposition B: instr(strSQL("Platform"), session("osversion")) > 0

Your code:

```
if a
    if b
        do alfa
    else
        do bravo
else
    do alfa
```

rewritten:

```
if not a or b
    do alfa
else
    do bravo
```

and now in ASP

```
<%
dim showButton, errMsg
showButton = "<input type='image' src='images/download2.gif' name='submit' value='submit' />"
errMsg = "<p style='font-weight:bold'> SOME ERROR MESSAGE</p>"
If session("var") <> "" Then
    If( instr(strSQL("Platform"), session("osversion")) > 0  ) Then 
        response.write showButton
    Else
        response.write errMsg
    End If
Else
    response.write showButton
End If
%>



<%
dim showButton, errMsg
showButton = "<input type='image' src='images/download2.gif' name='submit' value='submit' />"
errMsg = "<p style='font-weight:bold'> SOME ERROR MESSAGE</p>"
If session("var") = "" or  (instr(strSQL("Platform"), session("osversion")) > 0) Then 
    response.write showButton
Else
    response.write errMsg
End If
%>



<%
If session("var") = "" or (instr(strSQL("Platform"), session("osversion")) > 0) Then 
    response.write "<input type='image' src='images/download2.gif' name='submit' value='submit' />"
Else
    response.write "<p style='font-weight:bold'> SOME ERROR MESSAGE</p>"
End If
%>
```